# How to get rid of many IFs and make a system to differ elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

In this piece of code you can see a JSON request that fetches some data. I need some help to check certain opportunities of minimizing the code and getting iterations with FOR instead of many IFs. Also, it would be nice if you advise anything on the differentiation system (how to make elements differ from each other)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function deleteRow0() {
        $('p.row0').remove();
    }; 
    function deleteRow1() {
        $('p.row1').remove();
    }; 
    function deleteRow2() {
        $('p.row2').remove();
    }; 
    function deleteRow3() {
        $('p.row3').remove();
    }; 
    function deleteRow4() {
        $('p.row4').remove();        
    }; 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function hello2() {
        //GETTING JSON INFO
        $.getJSON("https://rawgit.com/Varinetz/e6cbadec972e76a340c41a65fcc2a6b3/raw/90191826a3bac2ff0761040ed1d95c59f14eaf26/frontend_test_table.json", function(json) {
            $('#table-cars').css("display", "grid");
            for (let counter = 0; counter < json.length; counter++) {
                $('#table-cars').append("<p class='row" + counter +" main-text'>" + json[counter].title + "<br/>" + "<span class='sub-text'>" + json[counter].description + "</span>" + "</p>"
                + "<p class='row" + counter +" main-text'>" + json[counter].year + "</p>" 
                + "<p id='color" + [counter] + "' class='row" + counter +" main-text'>" + json[counter].color + "</p>" 
                + "<p id='status" + [counter] + "' class='row" + counter +" main-text'>" + json[counter].status + "</p>" 
                + "<p class='row" + counter +" main-text'>" + json[counter].price + " руб." + "</p>" 
                + "<p class='row" + counter +" main-text'>" + "<button class='delete' onclick='deleteRow" + [counter] + "()'>Удалить</button>" + "</p>");
                // COLOR TEXT REPLACEMENT
                if ($('p#color0').text("red")){
                    $('p#color0').text("").append("<img src='red.png'>");
                }    
                if ($('p#color1').text("white")) {
                    $('p#color1').text("").append("<img src='white.png'>");
                }  
                if ($('p#color2').text("black")) {
                    $('p#color2').text("").append("<img src='black.png'>");
                }  
                if ($('p#color3').text("green")) {
                    $('p#color3').text("").append("<img src='green.png'>");
                } 
                if ($('p#color4').text("grey")) {
                    $('p#color4').text("").append("<img src='grey.png'>");
                } 
                // STATUS TEXT REPLACEMENT
                if ($('p#status0').text("pednding")) {
                    $('p#status0').text("").append("Ожидается");
                }    
                if ($('p#status1').text("out_of_stock")) {
                    $('p#status1').text("").append("Нет в наличии");
                }  
                if ($('p#status2').text("in_stock")) {
                    $('p#status2').text("").append("В наличии");
                }  
                if ($('p#status3').text("out_of_stock")) {
                    $('p#status3').text("").append("Нет в наличии");
                } 
                if ($('p#status4').text("in_stock")) {
                    $('p#status4').text("").append("В наличии");
                } 
        }

        });
    }
</script>
```

I expect this to be something like:
1) Iteration: For each p.row(i) {
compare it to many color (json.color)};
2) Any suggestion on differentiation system (i.e. changes in the FOR section, so it gives something easier to work with, not just simple p.row(n)). Of course, if it is possible.

Comment: `if ($('p#color0').text("red"))` is not even correct.... That is not looking if it is red, it sets it to red.

Comment: If the code works (which seems unlikely, but giving the benefit of the doubt), and you want a review of all of your code (not just the parts you want reviewed), you may be better served on [codereview.se], but review their [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) first.

Comment: Should I use something like

 if ($('p#color0:contains("red")')){
              $('p#color0').text("").append("<img src='red.png'>");

Comment: that contains line would not work because it returns a jquery object which is truthy. you would have to look for a length for it to be a truthy check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to rewrite the entire script, but in principle it would be something like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   var colors = ["red", "white", "black", "green", "grey"];
   if ($('p#color' + i).text() == colors[i]){
      $('p#color' + i).text("").append("<img src='" + colors[i] + ".png'>");
   }
}
```

**@Evik Ghazarian has a [quality solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56674895/4629519) for the Text Translation portion of your script. Since this is the accepted answer, he allowed me to copy his solution so that the answers would be together:**

```
function getTranslate(input) {
   var inputMap = {
      "pednding": "Ожидается",
      "out_of_stock": "Нет в наличии",
      "in_stock": "В наличии"
   }
   var defaultCode = input;
   return inputMap[input] || defaultCode;
}
for (let i = 0; i < 5 , i ++){
   var text = $("p#status"+i).text();
   $("p#status"+i).text("").append(getTranslate(text));
}
```

#### Dynamic Iteration Counters

@Barmar mentioned in the comments below that the `for` loops that set a max iteration via `i < 5` should actually be rewritten dynamically. I'll leave it to the OP to decide the best way to do this, but a good example might be something like `i < json.length` as used in the OP's original `for` loop.

Comment: It would be better to use `i < colors.length` instead of hard-coding the limit. And of course, the variable should be declared before the loop.

Comment: Maybe even use `colors.forEach(...)`

Comment: `.val()` should be `.text()`. `.val()` is only for inputs.

Comment: @Barmar I agree on ``.text()``. I just updated the code to reflect that. I disagree on ``colors.length`` or ``colors.forEach()`` because it's somewhat ambiguous in the OP where the colors or numbers are coming from. In the provided example they are hard-coded, so I followed suit. I'll leave it up to the OP to recode that as he desires.

Comment: @Barmar @Grant-Noe
Actually, after several tests I realized that the code doesn't work properly.
                   
<code>for (let i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                        let color = $("td#color"+i).text();                        
                        let img = 'img/';                        
                        $("td#color"+i).append(`<img src='${img}${color}.png'>`);                        
                      };</code>

It goes through all the td#color0-5, but eliminates all the data in the previous ones. I.e. if it is on the td#color5 - color0-4 are empty.

Comment: @AlekseiDemochko well I can see that the code itself and what you’re attempting to do has changed. I notice two grammatical errors right away looking at what you provided. First, the code you append needs to be surrounded by back ticks (`) to use variables with ${}. Research “template literals” for more info on that. Second, your ``for`` loop doesn’t require an apostrophe at the end. It would be tough to debug beyond that without a working example, but I’d recommend opening a new question with a working Snippet to get some help with this.

Comment: @AlekseiDemochko Looks like he did put it in backticks. In comments, backticks cause code formatting (you need to escape them or surround the code with triple-backticks, not `<code>`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all your code won't work because you are setting the text rather than comparing it. Second, you don't need to compare: just set the img src to text. Like below:

REMEMBER THIS IS FOR COLOR TEXT REPLACEMENT PART OF YOUR QUESTION

```
for (let i = 0; i < 5 , i ++){
     let color = $("p#color"+i).text() + ".png";
     $("p#color"+i).text("").append("<img src=" + color + ">");
}
```

FOR TEXT TRANSLATION YOU CAN USE:

```
function getTranslate(input) {
                                var inputMap = {
                                    "pednding": "Ожидается",
                                    "out_of_stock": "Нет в наличии",
                                    "in_stock": "В наличии"
                                }
                                var defaultCode = input;
                                return inputMap[input] || defaultCode;
                }
                for (let i = 0; i < 5 , i ++){
                    var text = $("p#status"+i).text();
                    $("p#status"+i).text("").append(getTranslate(text));
                }
```

Comment: How do you know why the OP doesn't need to compare? Maybe the text doesn't always equal the color, hence why it's wrapped in the "if".

Comment: because OP is getting the text from json[counter].color . It is in his/her code.

Comment: If you open the json link, counter 3 and counter 4 are both set to color "black". Wherever the data is sourced, the counter # is not always directly associated with a color.

Comment: it's fine since you chose your verified answer already. Anyhow you can take advantage of the translation part I just added. Have a good day.